# How to change LimitOffsetPagination

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pagination, limit, offset

I need to customize LimitOffsetPagination so it will show every time only unique objects.
So for example, as default it works like this:

Total customers: 24
Offset=0 Limit=5 => 1,2,3,4,5
Offset=1 Limit=5 => 2,3,4,5,6

**But I need it to work by this way** (maybe I should change the way it slices, but I don't know how):

Total customers: 24
Offset=0 Limit=5 => 1,2,3,4,5
Offset=1 Limit=5 => 6,7,8,9,10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is just standard [PageNumberPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style), and this is not related to uniqueness.

[LimitOffset](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-limit/) describes an `offset`, *# of records from the start* and `limit`, *number of rows to return*. This maps directly into SQL as:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100
```

Because of this, these two are equivalent:

- `my/url/?page=1&page_size=5`
- `my/url/?offset=5&limit=5`

Use the standard [PageNumberPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style), and change the page # / size parameter names if you **really** need to.  I would suggest not doing that, since limit/offset has a very direct analog in SQL, is a standard, and it would be confusing.

If you want to use the `PageNumberPagination` method with a user-settable page size you need to make a custom pagination class and define the `page_size` parameter:

```
class MyPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = "page_size"
    page_size = 5  # default size
    max_page_size = 100

# A version which pretends to be limit/offset pagination
class PageNumberAsLimitOffset(PageNumberPagination):
    page_query_param = "offset"   # this is the "page"
    page_size_query_param="limit" # this is the "page_size"
    page_size = 5
    max_page_size = 100
    
# Override the DRF default pagination
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "project.drf.pagination.MyPageNumberPagination"
}
```